# Why don't you need to pass the state to the reducer with react useReducer hook?

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

If we look at the standard example of increment, decrement with useReducer hook:

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

As I understand it, the useReducer function in the above code has bound 'dispatch' to the 'reducer' function so when we call dispatch it executes the reducer function. However, looking at the code the reducer function expects 2 params, however we only pass it one param when we execute dispatch - but it works. Why is this?.. many thanks.

Comment: `dispatch` is not the `reducer` function. It schedules a re-render and then calls `reducer` with the previous state and the parameter passed to `dispatch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dispatch()` function is a child function returned by the `useReducer()`. This gives it scoped access to the reducer that you passed into the `useReducer()`.

So when you call the `dispatch()` like so `dispatch({type: 'decrement'})` the `dispatch()` will take the action that you passed to it and grab the reducer that you passed into the `useReducer()` and it will pass in the state and the action that  you just passed into `dispatch()` to your reducer to get the desired state and use that value to set the state and re render the component.

So think of the `useReducer()` function something like the following:

```
const useReducer = (reducer, initialState) => {
  // react stuff being done here connect rendering and state
  // but for this example I will just hardcode the state to the initial state
  const state = initialState
  
  const dispatch = (action) => {
    // react will set the state with your reducer and re render the component
    React.dispatchState(reducer(state, action))
  }

  return [state, dispatch]
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** this is by no way the actual code react uses as the `useReducer()` but it will give you a good representation of how the code is working. You can see the source code here https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js and follow the bread crumbs to see how react actually does it.

Answer (score 1):

**the arguments in `reducer` are handled by the `useReducer` hook automatically**

the `dispatch` method in `useReducer` all it does is update the state with the appropriate action object in your case `decrement` or `increment` . So
when `dispatch` call `reducer` the arguments in `reducer` are handled by the  useReducer hook automatically : the state is known, and the action is just the argument of dispatch which is passed along to the reducer as its second argument.

Answer (score 1):

The `reducer` function and the `dispatch` function are not the same. Here's an *extremely simplified* example that might help you think conceptually about the data flow.

> Note that this is neither technically accurate nor really how the `useReducer` hook works. If you want to review the actual source code, here's the entrypoint for examination: the line where `useReducer` is exported from the codebase in the `18.2.0` release: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v18.2.0/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L87

```js
let state;

function useReducer (reducer, intialState) {
  state = intialState;

  const dispatch = (action) => {
    const next = reducer(state, action);
    const changed = !Object.is(state, next);
    state = next;
    if (changed) {
      // Causes React to re-render (code not shown)
    }
  };

  return [state, dispatch];
}
```

Comment: This is basically the exact same answer @EndlessCodebase posted an hour earlier.